# Does sequential position of squats and deadlifts within a workout effect the hormonal benefit?

Tags: bodybuilding, squats, muscle-gain, deadlifts, hormones

Folks like Charters William are fond of saying that squats and deadlifts are vital for natural body builders due to their function of stimulating testosterone and other muscle building hormone secretions.

He likes to encourage people to head straight to one or the other of those two as soon as they get to the gym, because even if one isn’t trying to target the legs/back as the object of that particular workout, it is necessary to stimulate the release of those muscle synthesising hormones in order to enhance the hypertrophic effect of one’s other lifts that may actually be the main focus for that day.

But can these same synergistic benefits still be reaped if, rather than starting one’s workout as Charters may suggest with these compound exercises, one finishes a day with deadlifts or squats?

It occurred to me that it may well do, because muscle protein synthesis is known to largely take place during sleep and recovery rather than during the workout itself anyway, so why should such sequencing concerns make any difference?

Comment: `so why should such sequencing concerns make any difference?` It most likely doesn't make much of a difference. I actually haven't heard people talk about this in years, so I thought it fell away.

Comment: FWIW, there doesn't seem to be a consensus on how long testosterone is elevated after exercise.  [This study for example](https://consensus.app/papers/recovery-heavy-resistance-exercise-skeletal-muscle-ahtiainen/5b8b030c52ca56ed8b6dae4250fb8393/) suggests that testosterone can be elevated as long as 6 days post workout (although on a sample size of 8 people).